# Use Feed dialog of Facebook API - Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I have integrated facebook api in my app code, there is a strange problem with parameters for feed dialog:

This code work perfect:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                kAppId, @"app_id",
                @"http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                @"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                               nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But if remove a single value not work:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                kAppId, @"app_id",
                @"Facebook Dialogs", @"name",
                @"Using Dialogs to interact with users.", @"description",
                               nil];
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

I have not need of @caption, @link, and @picture. I simple post a description to wall.

Comment: Remove kAppId in your params and try once.

Comment: Thk for the reply. I have tried to remove kAppId but the same result. Unfortunately not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this code,

```
    NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  @"Glueper App",@"name",@"http://m.facebook.com/apps/hackbookios/",@"link", nil], nil];
NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
// Dialog parameters
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"I'm using the Glueper App", @"name",
                               @"Glueper App", @"caption",
                               objSelGameStep.smsg, @"description",
                               @"http://m.facebook.com/apps/hackbookios/", @"link",
                               actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

this allows you to Post on FB wall....